# ssh login and git pull ask for username/password

Tags: git, ssh

I am on a Minimac 10.8.5 and I can execute "git pull" without username/password prompt.
But if I do an "ssh user@localhost" where "user" is my self, when I execute "git pull" I am prompt for username/password. As this will be executed via a script (python, javascript, php, it's a long way) the prompt is not good. 
The "sslVerify" is already set to false.
What could be the reason ?

Comment: Where is `git pull` pulling from? What does `git remote -v` give you? Try `git pull ssh://user@localhost` and see what happens.

Comment: the "git pull ssh://user@localhost/<path to project>" somehow worked, thanks a lot. You can set it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `git pull` trying to pull from? Try `git pull ssh://user@localhost`

Comment: so the solution is to pull via ssh when connected via ssh... it would be nice to understand why but thanks.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. To pull you have to be pulling from somewhere so you have to give git the location of the repository you're pulling from.